# Javascript: explain the meaning of :Number after a function declaration?

Tags: syntax, actionscript, return-type, function-declaration

*Remark from editor: Op miss-classified actionscript as javascript.*

I am new to Javascript and am confused by the following function declarations in ECMAScript.js2.

```
public class String extends Object {
  ...
  public native function charAt(pos:Number):String;
  public native function charCodeAt(pos:Number):Number;
  ...
```

What do ":String" and ":Number" mean? Are these initializer of some sort? How do they work?

Comment: @gdoron if you'll look at *Calling a Java Method from Handwritten JavaScript* section you'll see the difference

Comment: Check [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9916375/javascript-explain-the-meaning-of-number-after-a-function-declaration/9916388#comment12655708_9916388). om-nom-nom found what is it.

Answer (score 2):

That isn't `javascript`. as @om-nom-nom found out it's [Action-Script](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActionScript)

If it's still interesting you though it's not `javascript`, those are the return values of the functions.

From Wikipedia:

> ActionScript is an object-oriented language originally developed by Macromedia Inc. (now owned by Adobe Systems). It is a dialect of ECMAScript (meaning it is a superset of the syntax and semantics of the language more widely known as JavaScript), and is used primarily for the development of websites and software targeting the Adobe Flash Player platform, used on Web pages in the form of embedded SWF files.
>   ...
>   ...

Comment: The code were from ECMAScript.js2. Why are these code in Java?

Comment: @RyanChiang. Well I don't know but it is not `javascript`

Comment: While it is not a javascript (as in v.1 of post), your claim that this is Java is wrong too. Java has different order of type info: `Type Name` and not `Name Type`

Comment: @gdoron its ActionScript :) [here](https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib/blob/master/src/com/adobe/air/crypto/EncryptionKeyGenerator.as#L131) is the example

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9433/discussion-between-om-nom-nom-and-gdoron)

Comment: @om-nom-nom, I suggested you to write that as an answer because it's the only true answer...

Answer (score 2):

Number is the type of the expected parameter and String/Number the type of the return-value's

this does mean:

- charAt expects a Number as argument and returns a String
- charCodeAt expects a Number as argument and returns a Number

Answer (score 0):

FYI, this isn't javascript syntax (though it may be describing some javascript methods), but the `:String` and `:Number` at the end of the function declarations refer to the data type that the function returns.